# Twitter bootstrap dropdown show/hide events how do they work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to understand how the show/hide logic of a dropdown in twitter bootstrap works.

I can declare a dropdown menu in a navbar purely with HTML, and yet it seems that Javascript is involved with showing/hiding the dropdown. **Also the dropdown disappears if I focus out by clicking on an unrelated area on the page.**

**Question part 1:** Where can I find the Javascript code that is involved with Dropdowns in bootstrap?

**Question part 2:**  Is it somehow possible to tap into the event logic and execute some custom Javascript code when a certain dropdown receives **a focus out event**? For example so that I can hide another (unrelated) element on the page when the dropdown looses focus?

To be more precise:
Lets say I declare a bootstrap dropdown purely in HTML (this would be inside a `ul.nav.navbar-nav`):

```
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a id="mainmenu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
       role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Lectures <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Now somewhere else on the page I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="#background" style="display: none">
   <img src="...">
</div>
```

When I click on the dropdown button bootstrap will show the dropdown, but want two additional things to happen:

1. The `div#background` should be shown
2. Assuming I click somewhere outside the dropdown (which will cause bootstrap to close it), I want the `div#background` to be hidden again.

I think it should somehow be possible to register my own callback function on some bootstrap event and show/hide my `div` from that callback, like so:

```
/* just to illustrate my idea */
hide = function(element) {
    element.style.display = "none"
}

show = function(element) {
    element.style.display = "block"
}

}
```

So how and where could I register the `hide` and `show` functions such that they get called when I open/close the dropdown and also when I click on an unrelated area on the screen, which will cause the dropdown to close.

If this is possible to achieve purely in HTML by attaching some `data-*` elements to my `div#background` then I would like to know about that too.

Answer (score 0):

**First:**
Do you think about something like this?

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

Got it from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_dropdown.asp)

Second:

You can do call the dropdown link

```
$('#element').click( function(){
    $('#dropdownElement').dropdown();
});
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Not quite. I have update my question to explain more clearly what I am looking for.